# Trying to print out comments using PHP and MySQL and nothing gets printed

Tags: php, mysql

So I've written out simple code that SHOULD display every comment in the comment table (there is only 1 comment at the moment). The issue is - it doesn't.

What the code **SHOULD** do: display every comment in the comment table.

What it **DOESN'T** do: doesn't display ANY comments.

The code below doesn't work:

```
<!-- Posted Comments -->
                <?php
                    $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE adventureID = 2");
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
                    <div class="media">
                        <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                            <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h4 class="media-heading"><?php echo $row['userID']; ?>
                                <small><?php echo $row['dateTime']; ?></small>
                            </h4>
                        <?php echo $row['commentText']; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: No errors that im aware of.

Comment: have you created a connection and checked whether the connection has been to your database if made then , echo $result->num_rows; please

Comment: Give me a few minutes, had to leave my work space due to an assessment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to include the connection variable in mysqli_query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM comment WHERE adventureID = 2");
```

Where $con is the connection variable. Refer this [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp)

Answer (score 1):

If this is the only piece of code you have I was wondering if you have made a connection with the database in which the comments are stored in.

Making a connection could look a bit like this:

```
<?php
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$db= 'test';

// Create connection
$connect = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

// Check connection
if ($connect->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
?>
```

Comment: I've got that further up the page and it does connect to the database.